# Data disappear after refreshing the page when using browserHistory locally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, react-router

I had this issue where I was testing the react-router `browserHistory` on a webpack-dev-server and when I refresh any of the routes I get something like this `Cannot GET /pageurl`

In the production case it's a server configuration case as mentioned [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory), but it's a test and I'm using a development server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was so simple! as mentioned in [this article](http://jaketrent.com/post/pushstate-webpack-dev-server/) all I have to do is to add the following to `webpack.config.js` file

```
devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    historyApiFallback: true
}
```

and BAM it works!, alright I just wanted so share this because it wasn't easy to find the solution. bbye.